# How can I use the ODBC connection of another computer on my network?

Tags: ssh, tunnel, odbc

I'm not sure if I need to look at this problem a different way but here goes.

Computer A (windows XP) has an SSH Tunnel to the web server. Port 3306 on the web server is tunneled to port 3306 on Computer A (127.0.0.1:3306).

Computer A also has a MySQL ODBC connection using the SSH tunnel as the data source.

This setup is working great.

Computer B (windows 7) has a client that needs to use the same connection as Computer A.

I could easily just set up another SSH Tunnel on Computer B and recreate the ODBC connection but I'd rather not do that for a few reasons (client will have access to SSH keys, will be responsible to resetting the tunneled connection if there is a problem, etc).

Optimally I'd like to enable Computer B to use the ODBC connection of Computer A otherwise I'd like Computer B to use the SSH Tunnel from Computer A.

Is this possible, and if so how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can run the MySQL server on the web server as well? Is it a high traffic site?

Comment: @kobaltz I'm sorry, I don't fully understand the question. The reason I have Computer A using an SSH tunnel is because I need read only access to a single table for a client application.

Comment: With your current setup there is already an open port (3306) in Computer A that the ODBC driver is using to connect to the mysql service. You should be able to connect to that port from Computer B as well